# How to Properly Set SPF Record

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, spf, webmin

I am new to setting up server, this is my first time setting up mail server on my own. I am using ubuntu with webmin, everytime I send and receive from gmail, I had no problem.

I can receive emails from yahoo but everytime I send emails to yahoo, the mail never gotten to the recipient. So yeah, I want to setup the SPF properly

My server's IP is 203.128.78.51

This is my current setup

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:203.128.78.51 -all
```

In the Records list appears as:

> domain.com.   SPF 30  v=spf1 a mx ip4:203.128.78.51 -all

Is this correct?

I have already applied configuration and send more tests but still no success in sending mails to yahoo.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks before

Comment: You may check your spf record here: http://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx. Enter  the domain name for test.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. finally settled out to this one

v=spf1 a mx ip4:203.128.78.51 ip4:203.128.78.19 ~all

Comment: That is not a good idea, and to see why, you should carefully read the linked duplicate (hint: `~all` is a pointless entry).  You need to work out what's really wrong, and fix it, or stop using SPF.